# What does "" El yo Acuso ...." mean?

Tags: confusion

I have seen " El yo acuso..." in this headline below and in other places sometimes.
I wonder what does it mean?

Is it referring to the speaker being correct about what he is accusing others of?

Is it some political or cultural reference?

I looked it up in SpanishDict but it does not reveal anything?

Here is the link:

https://www.elmundo.es/cronica/2022/11/08/63650c0721efa0e27d8b45ab.html

Comment: Maybe it refers to 
[public denouncement](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/denunciation) or [open letter](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Open_letter)

Comment: @cocteau denouncement is not an English word. It's denunciation.///[I wonder what it means, not what does it mean]

Comment: @Lambie    thank you Lambie for your help but I'm a native English speaker and as a matter of fact "I wonder what does it mean " and "I wonder   what it means" are both correct.

Comment: [Denounce/denunciate](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/denounce-denunciate.3533692/) en ese enlace hay gente que jamás ha escuchado denunciate y en todo caso en enlace habla de denunciation y ya había hecho el aporte de J'Accuse...! que estaba dentro del enlace de open letter. Parece que es grande la necesidad de puntos, de apropiarse de las respuestas y de hacer correciones 0 aporte por acá.

Comment: @Bluelion7 No, /I wonder what it means./ is standard. And the other would be:  I wonder,  what does it mean? The indirect speech mode is often missed by people. They say: I wonder where did he go? It's I wonder where he went. Does it mean and did he go are question forms only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde los tiempos de Émile Zola el "**Yo Acuso**" se ha convirtió en una especie de declaración general donde su autor denuncia abiertamente un asunto a favor o en contra de un hecho injusto que estima que debe cambiar, normalmente se pide una rápida rectificación o un cambio de rumbo en la conducta o en la cuestión de quien corresponda proceder.

En el articulo al que haces referencia;

"Las venas secas de Doñana: **El yo acuso** del histórico director de la Estación Biológica del Parque".

En este caso es Javier Castroviejo, el jefe de los científicos del Parque Nacional, que tras varios años en su trabajo, denuncia y señala abiertamente **cual es la razón profunda por la que la mayor reserva ecológica de Europa está enferma** y como la falta de agua ha colocado al Parque Nacional al borde del desastre.

Castroviejo **acusa** o denuncia que durante décadas se han ignorado las leyes y se han guardado proyectos en el cajón.

De esta manera Castroviejo, a través de esta formula del "**Yo acuso**", intenta llamar la atención con una declaración general o carta abierta que llegue a la administración o a los auténticos responsables políticos, **que en definitiva serían los verdaderamente acusados**, para que tomen nota rápida y ponga una solución en marcha antes que sea demasiado tarde.

Answer (score 8):

**It is a reference to the famous open letter *J'Accuse...!* written by Émile Zola** in response to the Dreyfus affair.

Extracting from the [J'Accuse   !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%27Accuse...!) article in Wikipedia:

> "J'Accuse...!"  is an open letter that was published on 13 January 1898 in the newspaper L'Aurore by Émile Zola in response to the Dreyfus affair. Zola addressed President of France Félix Faure and accused his government of antisemitism and the unlawful jailing of Alfred Dreyfus
> ...
> The letter was printed on the front page of the newspaper and caused a stir in France and abroad.
> ...
> **As a result of the popularity of the letter,** even in the English-speaking world, **J'accuse! has become a common expression of outrage and accusation against someone powerful, whatever the merits of the accusation.**
>
> J'accuse! is one of the best-known newspaper articles in the world.